# Unable to handle the new window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a situation(mentioned below) due to which my selenium script is failing. Can someone help me?

I have a webpage where there is a save button, clicking on save button opens a new popup window. My requirement is to switch to the new window and click on one of the buttons(in the new window) which will automatically close the window and navigates to some other page. I have written a code which actually works fine but sometimes due to the application problem the new window is not getting closed. And due to this my script is failing. Here is the code I have used.

```
   public void test() {

          // i have two pages gets involved in this scenario

          driver.get("some url"); // user is in page 1

          // clicking on save button
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).click(); // a new window opens
          Set<String> winIDS = driver.getWindowHandles();
          if (winIDS.size() > 1) {
                 Iterator<String> it = winIDS.iterator();
                 it.next();
                 String childWindow = it.next();
                 driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).click();
                 //after clicking on this button the user is navigated to page2
          }


          // after clicking on the button in the new window the new window gets closed and the user is navigate to page 2 as mentioned before. 
          // To validate if that has happened i am using the below code so that my test case flow wont be stopped. But 
          // the code is getting hanged at the new window as the app fails to perform the button click action on the new window. 
          winIDS = driver.getWindowHandles();
          if(winIDS.size() > 1)
          {
                 Iterator<String> it = winIDS.iterator();
                 it.next();
                 String childWindow = it.next();
                 driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
                 driver.close();

                 //i m making the test failed here as the new window is not closed. 
          }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can see that you do twice the iteration to next window:

```
it.next();
String childWindow = **it.next();**
```

The second it.next() is obsolet.
Hope this solvs your issue.

Comment: I am gonna explain what I understand from the code I have written. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Iterator at the initial stage always points to memory location before the actual start. So the first it.next() points to the parent windows. So i have used it. The second it.next() points to the child window. That is why I have used it.next() twice.

Comment: You are right about the first part that you get the set of the windows available to the driver. But how do you know that the first is the parent and second is the child? Try to add a check based on windowID to make sure you switch to the right window.

Comment: I just tried now it is working. I put a check if the window i am switching to is the right window and script runs fine. Thanks for the solution  Diana R :)

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer.